# Inserir tupla direto com SQL em uma view Django

Tags: sql, django, django-2.0

Estou utilizando Django em dois projetos (vamos chamar de Projeto1 e Projeto2) que se relacionam e compartilham o mesmo banco, porém por serem projetos diferentes, não compartilham os mesmos apps.

Agora preciso criar, no Projeto1, informações que serão utilizadas no Projeto2. Mas como não tenho os apps não posso acessar o model e criar como faria se fosse tudo no mesmo projeto.

Já criei o model no Projeto2 e consegui acessar as informações em uma view do Projeto1:

```
class ListCategoriesView(ListView):

 template_name = 'account_plan/list_categories.html'

def get_context_data(self,  **kwargs):
    context = super(ListCategoriesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'categories': self.get_queryset()})
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM expenses_accountplan;""")
        categories = dictfetchall(cursor)

    return categories
```

No template as informações são exibidas corretamente, porém não estou conseguindo a CreateView com um insert para criar uma nova tupla. O que tentei:

```
class CreateCategoryView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'account_plan/create_category.html'
    success_url = 'account_plan/list'

def insert(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = '''INSERT INTO expenses_accountplan (category) VALUES ('categoria2');'''

    cursor.execute(query)
    transaction.commit()

def form_valid(self, form):
    return super(CreateCategoryView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return self.success_url
```

Isso está retornando o seguinte erro:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /units/account_plan/create
>   CreateCategoryView is missing a QuerySet. Define CreateCategoryView.model, CreateCategoryView.queryset, or override CreateCategoryView.get_queryset().

Como posso fazer isso? Ou tem alguma forma melhor de acessar dados do model do outro projeto? Sinto que ficar usando comandos SQL no Django não é muito adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Passei por uma situação semelhante a qual resolvi utilizando Django Rest Framework para realizar as operações. Crie os os endpoints no projeto 2 e acesse através do projeto 1, você poderá criar views para buscar, inserir, editar e deletar informações no projeto 2 e acessar tudo através do projeto 1 sem necessidade de utilizar SQL manualmente dentro das views. No link abaixo você encontrara um tutorial para criar sua api utilizando DRF: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-rest-api-with-django-a-test-driven-approach-part-1
Neste tutorial você verá como criar a API com todas as operações e ainda com autenticação.